# Concatenate two columns and output the result - ASP.NET Core 7 Razor pages

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, razor-pages

How can I concatenate two fields returned from SQL Server into one?

I am very new to ASP.NET Core Razor pages, trying to learn. I have done many of the basic tutorial but have no idea how to do this.

Database used is SQL Server, I have a table with three columns.

Model definition:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
 
namespace AssetRegisterNumbers.Models;

[PrimaryKey(nameof(Halo_Asset_Type))]
public partial class HaloAssetNumbers
{
    public string Halo_Asset_Type { get; set; }
    public string Asset_Type_Prefix { get; set; }
    public int Asset_Last_Number { get; set; }
}
```

Current `index.cshtml`:

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}
 
<h1>Index</h1>
 
<p>
     <a asp-page="Create">Create New</a>
 </p>
<table class="table">
     <thead>
         <tr>
            <th>
                 @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.HaloAssetNumbers[0].Asset_Type_Prefix)
             </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.HaloAssetNumbers[0].Asset_Last_Number)
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
     <tbody>
@foreach (var item in Model.HaloAssetNumbers) {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Asset_Type_Prefix)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Asset_Last_Number)
            </td>
            <td>
                <a asp-page="./Edit" asp-route-id="@item.Halo_Asset_Type">Edit</a> |
                <a asp-page="./Details" asp-route-id="@item.Halo_Asset_Type">Details</a> |
                <a asp-page="./Delete" asp-route-id="@item.Halo_Asset_Type">Delete</a>
            </td>
         </tr>
 }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Current `Index.cshtml.cs`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using AssetRegisterNumbers.Data;
using AssetRegisterNumbers.Models;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

namespace AssetRegisterNumbers.Pages.AssetNumbers
{
    public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly AssetRegisterNumbers.Data.AssetRegisterNumbersContext _context;

        public IndexModel(AssetRegisterNumbers.Data.AssetRegisterNumbersContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public IList<HaloAssetNumbers> HaloAssetNumbers { get;set; } = default!;
        
        public async Task OnGetAsync()
        {
            if (_context.HaloAssetNumbers != null)
            {
                HaloAssetNumbers = await _context.HaloAssetNumbers.ToListAsync();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

These are straight from the scaffold build Razor pages using Entity Framework Core (CRUD).

What I would like to do is concatenate the two columns `Asset_Type_Prefix` and `Asset_Last_number` into a single field and display this on the page. Note one is a string the other is an integer.

If possible I would like to add leading zeroes to each number dependent on the `Asset_type`.

- asset type 1 = 6 digits with leading zeroes
- asset type 2 = 7 digits with leading zeroes
- asset type 3 = just the value.

This concatenated field will not be used in further parts of the application as editing and creation will rely on the ability to increment the integer.

As I said I am new to this and am trying to get my head around how to do things.

Thanks in advance

Glyn

Comment: Simply add them: `<td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Asset_Type_Prefix)@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Asset_Last_Number)</td>` into one cell.

Comment: Thanks, now I just nee to work out how to ad leading zeroes.

Comment: Try `.ToString("D5")` - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings

Answer (score 1):

You can use the $ symbol in String Interpolation to concatenate Asset_Type_Prefix and Asset_Last_Number into a string, then use PadLeft method to add leading zeros based on the value of Asset_Type to ensure that the length of the field meets the requirements:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.HaloAssetNumbers) {
        <tr>
            <td>
                  
                @{
                        string concatenatedField = $"{item.Asset_Type_Prefix}{item.Asset_Last_Number}";

                       
                        if (item.Halo_Asset_Type == "1")
                        {
                            concatenatedField = concatenatedField.PadLeft(6, '0'); 
                        }
                        else if (item.Halo_Asset_Type == "2")
                        {
                            concatenatedField = concatenatedField.PadLeft(7, '0'); 
                        }

                        @concatenatedField
                    } 
             </td>
    <td>
        <a asp-page="./Edit" asp-route-id="@item.Halo_Asset_Type">Edit</a> |
        <a asp-page="./Details" asp-route-id="@item.Halo_Asset_Type">Details</a> |
        <a asp-page="./Delete" asp-route-id="@item.Halo_Asset_Type">Delete</a>
    </td>
</tr>
}
```

[image]